# Drag and drop file and send with post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm attempting to create a drag and drop file upload form. I got the drag and drop part working, but I can't figure out how to submit the file once I have it. I can't use ajax, the form needs to redirect just like an html upload form would.

Here's my drag and drop code.

```
$("html").on("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files)
});
```

Normally when posting data generated through javscript I use the function below, but it doesn't work for files as you can't set file inputs.

```
function post(path, data) {
  let form = $('<form>')
    .attr({
      method: 'post',
      path: path
    })
    .appendTo('body')

  for(let key in data) {
    if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    $('<input>')
      .attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: key,
        value: data[key]
      })
      .appendTo(form)
  }

  form.submit()
}
```